# If $a$ and $b$ are non-negative real numbers, prove that $ab(a+b) \leq a^2+b^2$.

Tags: geometry, inequality

> If $a$ and $b$ are non-negative real numbers, prove that $ab(a+b) \leq a^2+b^2$.

Is is a geometric mean? How to prove it?

Answer (score 13):

Note that if $a+b\le 2$, then $ab(a+b)\le 2ab$. And we have $2ab\le a^2+b^2$, since $(a-b)^2\ge 0$. So the desired inequality **does** hold if $a+b\le 2$.

If the condition $a+b\le 2$ is violated, then the inequality can fail. For let $a=b=k$. Then $ab(a+b)=2k^3$ and $a^2+b^2=2k^2$. If $k\gt 1$ then $2k^3\gt 2k^2$.

Answer (score 7):

The statement as given is false.  Take $a=b=3$.  Then $ab(a+b)=54$, while $a^2+b^2=18$.

Comment: More generally, it is falce whenever $a,b>1$, since the left hand side, when expanded out, is $a^2 b +b^2 a$, with the first term larger thatn $a^2$ and the second term larger than $b^2$.

Comment: @Aaron *false ${}{}$

Comment: On the other hand, if the problem is restricted to $a,b\in(0,1)$, then @Aaron's calculation shows that the statement is true.

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends on the domain of $a$ and $b$. For $a,b >1$ it is false, but for $a,b \le 1$ it is true!